# Opening multiple folders in the same File Explorer window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-11, microsoft-file-explorer

In Windows 11 you can open multiple folders in the same window as "tabs" ([example](https://www.pcworld.com/article/1430331/use-the-new-tabbed-file-explorer-to-simplify-your-life.html#:%7E:text=File%20Explorer%20tabs%20are%20already,button%20next%20to%20the%20tab.)).
Does Python have a way to open multiple folders in the same File Explorer window?

I know you can open multiple folders with `os.startfile()`, but it opens them in separate windows.
And yes, I have the `"Open each folder in the same window"` option enabled and `"Launch folder windows in a separate process"` disabled in File Explorer.

I understand that this is a new feature, so it's probably not possible yet, but I'm just wondering if it is.

[Example of File Explorer with multiple tabs open in same window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0KD8.jpg)

### What I tried

I tried `os.startfile()`, creating a batch file and running it, and `subprocess.Popen()`.

### What I expected to happen

I expected it to open them in the same window.

### What actually resulted

It opened them in separate windows.